# movenext and moveprevious navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net

A dropdownlist with numerous items, movenext and moveprevious navigation buttons to display an image for each selected item. Each image is displayed in the same image control. The image data in the database is simply a path to the image file.

Using the DataReader and stored procedure for data, how do I move next and previous without having to access the database each time?

ASP.NET 4, C#, MS SQL Server 2008

Comment: Why the silence on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataReader` by definition works only in connected mode, requires an open connection and in fact translates in a SQL Cursor so it does access the database every time you do a move next.

if you want to fetch all image paths at once and then work disconnected with no more roundtrips on the database use a `DataSet` instead.

Comment: So, would using a DataSet be better than using just the DataReader? I've heard that using a DataSet is slower.